# Apache Geode - Support

Tags: geode

I work for a company does not like to use open source.  The reason is because there generally is no production support if an issue happens.   For Apache Geode, is there any way to obtain a "support" contract for production issues?

Answer (score 1):

[VMware](https://www.vmware.com/) is the main contributor to Apache Geode. You can purchase support though VMware’s brand, GemFire. Please have a look at [Tanzu GemFire](https://tanzu.vmware.com/gemfire) for more details.